# Start new activity from activity in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am new to using viewpager to swipe between activities and currently have it set up like this:

MainActivity.Java:

```
    package com.example.elfho.nceatracker;

    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));

        }
    }
```

ModelObject.Java:

```
public enum ModelObject {

        ONE(R.string.level1, R.layout.activity_level1),
        TWO(R.string.level2, R.layout.activity_level2),
        THREE(R.string.level3, R.layout.activity_level3);

        private int mTitleResId;
        private int mLayoutResId;

        ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
            mTitleResId = titleResId;
            mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
        }

        public int getTitleResId() {
            return mTitleResId;
        }

        public int getLayoutResId() {
            return mLayoutResId;
        }
     }
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java:

```
public enum ModelObject {

ONE(R.string.level1, R.layout.activity_level1),
TWO(R.string.level2, R.layout.activity_level2),
THREE(R.string.level3, R.layout.activity_level3);

private int mTitleResId;
private int mLayoutResId;

ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
    mTitleResId = titleResId;
    mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
}

public int getTitleResId() {
    return mTitleResId;
}

public int getLayoutResId() {
    return mLayoutResId;
 }

}
```

This makes the app swipe between my three activities, activity_level1, activity_level2, and activity_level3.
However, I have not created specific java files for these activities because I don't need to in order to open them correctly.
If I now want to open a new activity from one of these 3 activities, where would I need to write the code to make this work?

Comment: In your adapter class you can launch another activity using mainactivity context.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I'm sorry but I'm quite new to this. Would you be able to clarify what you mean by using mainactivity context? If you could provide even very rough pseudo code as an explanation I'd be very happy to approve your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html. Here you can see why we use context.

Like this way you can call another activity.

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends Your_adapter_method {
 private Context context; 

 public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
      this.context = context;     //Main Activity Context
 }

 public View getView(...){
     View v;
     v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         void onClick() {
              Intent intent= new Intent(context, secondactivity.class);
              intent.putextra("your_extra","your_class_value");
              context.startActivity(intent); //Must use context to start activity.
         }
     });
 }
}
```

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Welcome glad to help.!

Comment: What parameter is expected in the getView function?

Comment: It contains (position,view,viewgroup) based on adapter class.